# Inconsistent results when using an iPad to access and send HTML/PHP forms

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, ipad

I have built a website that uses HTML, CSS, PHP and MySQL.  The purpose of the website is to allow students to build a word bank.  The data is sent and stored in a MySQL database via PHP/HTML forms.  The information is displayed using HTML/CSS/PHP.

I haven't experienced any problems with the system UNTIL the children have been accessing it in school, using iPads to access/explore the website.

The problem I'm having is simple (and also infuriating!): sometimes the children can't login to the website - every time they press the 'login' form submit button, the form 'refuses' to be submitted (returning them to the same login page, as if it had just been refreshed).  The same problem also occurs when they're trying to upload a word to the database - the form submit button 'refuses' to submit the data.
Basically: the submit buttons can be 'clicked', but they don't do what they're supposed to do.

Here's the code that I've written for the login system:

```
<?php

if($_POST){

    if(login( $_POST['user'],$_POST['pass']) ){

            echo "<a href=index.php>Continue.</a>";
            $_SESSION['user'] = strtolower($_POST['user']);

            } else { }

} else {

?>

Please login
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="user" value="Username">
  <br />
  <input type="password" name="pass" value="Password">
  <br />
  <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
</form>

<?php

}

?>
```

I'm not really sure what the problem could be - I'd guess (and almost hope) that it's a problem with my code (my use of sessions, maybe?) - but if it was, then why does the system work fine sometimes, and then at other times so inconsistently?  Is it a problem related to iPads?

I hope I've made myself clear enough for any helpful suggestions.

Comment: the `} else {}` right after `$_SESSION['user']...` has nothing to do here, and should cause a PHP error due to the `else` right after

Answer (score 0):

You should use session_start function to start or resume exist session.

Just append a session_start function at the begin of your code.

```
<?php
session_start();


if($_POST){
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Apologies for not being clear, but the login code I quoted above is actually included into my main index file which already uses session_start(); at the beginning of that index file's code.  Could my use of includes/sessions in this way be causing the problems?

Comment: Are you using any css style for submit button or form?

Comment: yes: input { height: 40px; width: 300px; font-family: arial; font-size: 16pt; color: navy; background-color: #ffffcc; }

Comment: could css style for submit buttons/input fields be the problem?

Comment: Are you shure, that form doesn't have any listener to submit event?

Try to use <button type="submit" name="login">Login</button>

Comment: What do you mean by "listener to submit event"?  Do you mean javascript events like onClick etc?  If so: no, there are none of those.  Could it be a problem with the ipads?  Could it be related to the school's network?